# Typed dataset as generic return type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have two methods that return a typed dataset.
I would like to have only one generic method.

```
private TypedDataSet GetData(string query, string tblName)
{
   string conString = .... ;     
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
   {
      using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
      {
         cmd.Connection = con;
         sda.SelectCommand = cmd;             

         using (TypedDataSet tds = new TypedDataSet ())
         {
            sda.Fill(tds , tblName);
            return tds ;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you need to be generic here?

Comment: The return value needs to be generic

Comment: I see only a single type to return, which is `TypedDataset`. Apart from this be aware that after returning that instance within the method, you´re disposing it with `using`, so you can´t to much with it.

Comment: You mean `private T GetData<T>(string query, string tblName) where T : DataSet, new()`? Been a long time since I've had to resort to those objects.

Comment: We need more information. We need to know your model. We need to know why you want to have generics in this.

Comment: The 2 functions are private Customers GetData(string query, string tblName) and private Employees GetData(string query, string tblName) and I want to have only one function for that. I thought generics would be the right approach for that. I tried with casts but coud not get it.

Comment: So, does my code work or not?

Comment: I tried same deklaration before, but I dont know how to replace

using (TypedDataSet tds = new TypedDataSet ())
         {
            sda.Fill(tds , tblName);
            return tds ;
         }

Comment: Inside your method, replace `TypedDataSet` with `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly simple, just change your method signature to use a generic type and add constraints, for example:

```
private T GetData<T>(string query, string tblName) 
    where T : DataSet, new()
{
    string conString = .... ;     
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;             

            // Use T here instead of TypedDataSet
            using (T tds = new T())
            {
                sda.Fill(tds , tblName);
                return tds;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Now the method can be called like this:

```
var typedDataSet = GetData<TypedDataSet>("foo", "bar");
```

Note the generic types constraints are `DataSet` to ensure you can pass it into the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` method and `new()` so you can create the instance inside the method.

Note: the major problem with this method is that the SQL query can be absolutely anything, so you would need to be super careful with them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me perfectly!
What do you mean with "SQL query can be absolutely anything"?